# Preserve embedded objects when converting a Word File to PDF using Acrobat Pro 9

Tags: attachments, adobe-acrobat

I thought this was a basic feature but I can't seem to find a solution:

If I want to convert a Word file which has other files embedded as an object to PDF, the embedded Word symbol is not clickable anymore - the file was not embedded. The current workaround is to add attachments afterwards. The problem is that I can't link those files with an icon. Do you know a solution to this issue?

Thanks for an answer!

Answer (score 1):

This sort of feature is not standard in Word to PDF conversion.

It looks like the best you can do when using Adobe Acrobat is to add a link to the icon with an action that executes a menu item. If you make this action open the Attachments panel then at least you'll be able to see the attachment.